# Pandas secondary y axis for boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I'd like to use a secondary y-axis for some boxplots in pandas, but it doesn't seem available.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.random.random((10, 5))
data[:,-1] += 10  # offset one column
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, using the default line plot it's easy enough to plot to a second y-axis:

```
df.plot(kind='line', secondary_y=[4])
```

[image: normal line plot]

But if I use boxplot style, it doesn't work:

```
df.plot(kind='box', secondary_y=[4])
```

[image: box plot without second yaxis]

Is there any way (maybe through matplotlib) I can get pandas to plot 2 axes for boxplot? Using the `boxplot()` method would be preferable, but I'll take `plot()`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually not that hard with matplotlib.

```
In [22]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()

In [23]: df[[0, 1, 2, 3]].plot(kind='box', ax=ax)
Out[23]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x4890978>

In [24]: ax2 = ax.twinx()

In [25]: ax2.boxplot(df[4], positions=[4])

In [27]: ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
Out[27]: (0, 5)
```

There's still some cleanup with the styling, ticklabels etc. But that should get you started.

Comment: Excellent. The ``positions`` argument is what I failed to see when I dug around. Thanks!